# Brew - Reinstall a package but without previously selected option

Tags: thread-safety, homebrew, php-7

I recently installed PHP 7.0 with threading support using brew:

```
brew install php70 --with-httpd24 --with-thread-safety
```

But this led me to some issues, and I wand to remove the threading support again.

I tried the following command:

```
brew reinstall php70 --with-httpd24
```

Basically the same, but without `--with-thread-safety`, but it seams brew will automatically add it again:

```
brew reinstall php70 --with-httpd24
==> Reinstalling homebrew/php/php70 --with-httpd24 --with-thread-safety
==> Downloading https://php.net/get/php-7.0.18.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
```

The option `--without-thread-safety` does not exist, so how to I unselect the `--with-thread-safety` option?

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/5327#issuecomment-439495923

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t do that with `brew reinstall`.

Use `brew uninstall php70` then `brew install php70 --with-httpd24`.